# Trouble querying Solr from JavaScript and displaying results, getting nothing

Tags: javascript, json, apache, solr

I am trying working off of https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON tutorial. I have put my url for solr in the code, copied from solr admin query result to make sure the query should return something.

I try typing in "title:Asian" into text box (that field/search term combo returned results in the admin console query) but when the button is hit, textbox just clears and nothing in output spot.

I used the dev tools from [F12] key of browser to check console and see there was no errors given there, such as for syntax, so not due to that.

Perhaps I am understanding how the url for query works or should be here? If I leave out local host part as shown I just get error for not specifying local full path.

Does anyone see anything wrong here, or have any ideas/tips of what more to do to try and solve the issue?

[ If I must do/add anything else to make good/better post here, please do explain so I can fix :) ]

```js
<html>
<head>
<title>Solr Ajax Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script language="Javascript">
// derived from http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) 
{
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla/Safari
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    };

    var params = getstandardargs().concat(getquerystring());
    var strData = params.join('&');
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(strData);
//document.getElementById("raw").innerHTML = strData;
    return false;
}

function getstandardargs() {
    var params = [
        'wt=json'
        , 'indent=on'
        , 'hl=true'
        ];

    return params;
}
function getquerystring() {
  var form = document.forms['f1'];
  var query = form.query.value;
  qstr = 'q=' + escape(query);
  return qstr;
}

// this function does all the work of parsing the solr response and updating the page.
function updatepage(str)
{
  document.getElementById("raw").innerHTML = str;
  var rsp = eval("("+str+")"); // use eval to parse Solr's JSON response
  var html = "<br>numFound=" + rsp.response.numFound;
  var first = rsp.response.docs[0];
  html += "<br>product name=" + first.name;
  var hl = rsp.highlighting[first.id];
  if (hl.name != null) { html += "<br>name highlighted: " + hl.name[0]; }
  if (hl.features != null) { html += "<br>features highligted: " + hl.features[0]; }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="f1" onsubmit='xmlhttpPost("http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/select?")'>
  <p>query: <input name="query" type="text">
  <input value="Go" type="submit"></p>

<div id="result"></div>
<p/><pre>Raw JSON String/output: <div id="raw"></div></pre>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be aware that if you're opening this from a different server than the Solr server itself (same host:port), the request will be denied because of cross site requests being blocked by default.

Comment: I just have solr running on my laptop on the 8983 port, and on same computer opened up that html file in my firefox browser from which I can view the solr admin console.

Comment: That's probably not going to work, as a local opened file won't have access to read arbitrary content through javascript - it'll have to be opened from the same `host:port` combination as it should be read from, or the source being read has to present the approriate CORS headers.

Comment: How do I go about that? Pretty new to this whole port thing.

Comment: You'd probably want to stick a small web service in front of Solr instead of going directly from the browser. Security is usually also an issue, since Solr isn't meant to be stuck directly on the internet by default.